# ACE_TRACE macro not working

Tags: c++, ace

I am following the book **ACE Programmer's Guide, The: Practical Design Patterns for Network and Systems Programming** By Stephen D. Huston, James CE Johnson, Umar Syyid. In this book in the very beginning there is a listing:

```
#include "ace/Log_Msg.h"

void foo (void);

int ACE_TMAIN (int, ACE_TCHAR *[])
{
    ACE_TRACE(ACE_TEXT ("main"));

    ACE_DEBUG ((LM_INFO, ACE_TEXT ("%IHi Mom\n")));
    foo();
    ACE_DEBUG ((LM_INFO, ACE_TEXT ("%IGoodnight\n")));

    return 0;
}

void foo (void)
{
    ACE_TRACE (ACE_TEXT ("foo"));

    ACE_DEBUG ((LM_INFO, ACE_TEXT ("%IHowdy Pardner\n")));
}
```

As the book says, this code should have output:

```
(1024) calling main in file `Simple1.cpp' on line 7
   Hi Mom
   (1024) calling foo in file `Simple1.cpp' on line 18
      Howdy Pardner
   (1024) leaving foo
   Goodnight
(1024) leaving main
```

But it's outputting:

```
Hi Mom
Howdy Pardner
Goodnight
```

I'm running it in Windows 7, Visual C++ 2010, as a Win32 console application. Is there any other way to learn ACE easily? It seems tedious to learn in this way. Qt has its own cross-platform networking library. Does ACE has any advantage over Qt's library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you haven't defined `ACE_NTRACE`, and so `ACE_TRACE` expands to nothing by default. Add this to your code:

```
#define ACE_NTRACE 0
```

Comment: I don't have 15 reputations, that's why I can't upvote it :(. Can you suggest me any good resource to learn ACE?

Comment: This [online ACE tutorial](http://www.huihoo.org/ace_tao/ACE-5.2+TAO-1.2/ACE_wrappers/docs/tutorials/online-tutorials.html) can help you get started...

Comment: I think this tutorial is outdated. When I try to compile the first program it shows errors. For instance, when I compile the program of this page [link](http://www.huihoo.org/ace_tao/ACE-5.2+TAO-1.2/ACE_wrappers/docs/tutorials/001/page02.html), I get error like:
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'acceptor.h': No such file or directory. When I change the 'acceptor.h' with 'ace/Acceptor.h', a bunch of errors occur. Can you please help me.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice it. It's not ACE header, rather a custom header. Thanks once again for you assistance.